# ASP.Net MVC 6 PartialView model binding confusion

Tags: asp.net-core-mvc

**Background**
We need to submit model with items. For that purpose, we make this complex model:

```
public class PaymentViewModel
{
  public decimal? Payment { get; set; }
  public string Description { get; set; }

  public List<SplittedPaymentViewModel> SplittedPayment { get; set; } = new List<SplittedPaymentViewModel>();
}

public class SplittedPaymentViewModel
{
  public short SplittedPaymentId { get; set; }
  public decimal? Payment { get; set; }
  public string Description { get; set; }
}
```

For rendering html, we this two views, one regular: **CreatePayment**

```
@model ZevApp.ViewModels.Record.PaymentViewModel
...
<input class="form-control" asp-for="Payment" type="number" />
<input class="form-control" asp-for="Description" />
...
<div class="panel-body" id="SplittedPayments">
@foreach (var spItem in Model.SplittedPayment)
{
  @Html.Partial("SplittedPaymentPartial", spItem);
}
...
</div>
```

And the other Partial: **SplittedPaymentPartial**

```
@model ZevApp.ViewModels.Record.SplittedPaymentViewModel
...
<input class="form-control" asp-for="Payment" type="number" />
<input class="form-control" asp-for="Description" />
...
```

As you can see, from the first view, we call partial view and pass them item by item form the *SplittedPayment* list.

**Unexpectedly behavior**
We run the code but unexpectedly behavior is occur:
Each partial view bind *Payment* and *Description* form parent *PaymentViewModel*, not from a passed item?

Does anybody know what is wrong?

Each view define model at the beginning of the file.

From the controller we return *PaymentViewModel*, and for a test, there are tree *SplittedPaymentViewModel*s. But we can't see values from the items.

Comment: Here is [test project](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B5bsSH-06GTYSU1kaDQxQS02NUU/view?usp=sharing) and use case steps:

1. Run the project, click on the link "CreatePayment". Initialized data are well bonded.

2. Click Submit button.

3. After rendering the page, you can see that for each _SplittedPayment_, _Payment_ and _Description_ were bonded from _PaymentViewModel_ not form _SplittedPayment_.

If you put break point on debug mode on _public IActionResult CreatePayment(PaymentViewModel model)_ you can see that model is OK - it contains 2 items

Comment: This is strange! Why don't add a new field to SplittedPaymentViewModel and bind it to a input in the partial view? (Or you may use Id for this purpose.) Thus you'll be sure that the view inputs are bound to the correct model instance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I found that problem was **CreatePayment.cshtml** (thanks to the people from MVC community). It doesn't provide any information about the **spItem** expression when invoking the partial view.

```
var savePrefix = ViewData.TemplateInfo.HtmlFieldPrefix;
for (var i = 0; i < Model.SplittedPayment.Count; i++)
{
  ViewData.TemplateInfo.HtmlFieldPrefix = Html.NameFor(m => m.SplittedPayment[i]);

  var spItem = Model.SplittedPayment[i];
  @Html.Partial("SplittedPaymentPartial", spItem);

  ViewData.TemplateInfo.HtmlFieldPrefix = savePrefix;
}
```

You can find full description on https://github.com/aspnet/Mvc/issues/4106